# in textformField how to use initialValue and controller both at same time?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-web

i want to use controller and initialValue both at same time but showing error

```
TextFormField(
  controller: txtEmail,
  initialValue: initialValues['emailAddress'],
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
    label: Text('Email Address'),
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: accentColor)),
   enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: iconColor))
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use the controller and initial value at the same time.
It's either you use the `initialValue` with `onChanged` property or use the controller.
If you need the controller and initial value, then you can assign your initial value to the `controller.text`

```html
final textController = TextEditingController();

void initState(){
 textController.text = 'your initial value';
 
 super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because text form field want assert(initialValue == null || controller == null). so you can set initialValue text into controller

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
txtEmail.text = initialValues['emailAddress'];
```

Remove initialValue:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: txtEmail,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
    label: Text('Email Address'),
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: accentColor)),
   enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: iconColor))
  ),
),
```